# How to detect if an object variable has been changed?

Tags: javascript

I have a class that represents a fence, internally its made up from rectangle and circle marker objects (also my classes). The fence has 4 variables - x1, x2, y1 and y2. If any of these changes I have to modify or rebuild the internal marker objects.

Storing and checking the 4 values isn't such a big deal but this is just the first of my world object classes and there will be ones with much longer lists of variables. 
Is there any good way of checking whether any of these has changed or trigger something on change without explicitly storing double values and checking each time the canvas is redrawn? Something like a property in vb.net or such?

Comment: You can use a variable to do dirty checking.

Comment: Do you mean an object property or a scope variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var fence= {
   set x1(){
      alert('change');
      this.rebuild();
   },
   rebuild: function(){}
}
```

Also

```
function Fence(val){
    var value = val;

    this.__defineGetter__("x1", function(){
        return value;
    });

    this.__defineSetter__("x1", function(val){
        alert('change');
        this.rebuild();
    });
    this.rebuild = function(){};
}
var fence = new Fence();
```

Comment: Sorry, I blew through it really quick. My bad. It should work now.

Comment: Here is a good read about getters and setters: http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-getters-and-setters/

Comment: Whoa, I had no idea about that. Thanks for the link.

Comment: Yeah, no problem. I really like the direction that javascript is heading.

Comment: `__defineGetter__` and `__defineSetter__` have both been dropped from the standards, so they may lose support in future browsers. They also don't exist in IE 10 and below.

Answer (score 1):

Using the object posted in the code below, you can achieve it quite easily:

```
function Fence() {
    // constructor
}

Fence.prototype.refresh = function() {
    // change the refresh code here
    console.log(this.x1 + "," + this.y1 + "," + this.x2 + "," + this.y2);
};

// must be called after the prototype.refresh function is defined
RefreshExtender.addRefreshProperties(Fence, [
        new RefreshExtender.Property("x1", 0), // propertyName, defaultValue[, refreshFunction]
        new RefreshExtender.Property("y1", 0, function() { console.log('Refresh only y1 property.'); }),
        new RefreshExtender.Property("x2", 0),
        new RefreshExtender.Property("y2", 0)
    ]);
```

Then when using it:

```
var fence = new Fence();
fence.x1 = 20;
// Outputs: "20,0,0,0"
```

Now if you change multiple properties at once, it will only call the refresh function after all the properties have been set. For example:

```
fence.x1 = 10; 
fence.x2 = 20;
// Outputs: "10,0,20,0 (Outputs only ONCE)"
```

If we update the `y1` property, it will execute the function passed in when creating the property:

```
fence.y1 = 30;
// Outputs: "Refresh only y1 property."
```

Refresh Extender:

```
var RefreshExtender = {
    addRefreshProperties: function(baseType, properties) {
        function defineProperty(property) {
            Object.defineProperty(baseType.prototype, property.name, {
                get: function() {
                    var val = this["_" + property.name];
                    if (typeof val === "undefined") {
                        return property.defaultValue;
                    }
                    return val;
                },
                set: function(val) {
                    var shouldRefresh = this["_" + property.name] !== val;
                    this["_" + property.name] = val;
                    if (shouldRefresh) {
                        if (typeof property.refreshFunction === "function") {
                            property.refreshFunction();
                        }
                        else {
                            this.refresh();
                        }
                    }
                },
                enumerable: true,
                configurable: true
            });
        }

        for (var i = 0, l = properties.length; i < l; i++) {
            defineProperty(properties[i]);
        }

        var oldRefreshFunction = baseType.prototype.refresh;

        baseType.prototype.refresh = RefreshExtender._executeOnce(oldRefreshFunction);
    },
    Property : function(name, defaultValue, refreshFunction) {
        this.name            = name;
        this.defaultValue    = defaultValue;
        if (typeof refreshFunction === "function") {
            this.refreshFunction = RefreshExtender._executeOnce(refreshFunction);
        }
    },
    _executeOnce : function(originalFunc) {
        var isRefreshing = false,
            func = function() {
                var _this = this;
                if (!isRefreshing) {
                    isRefreshing = true;
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        isRefreshing = false;
                        originalFunc.call(_this);
                    }, 0);
                }
            };

        return func;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a closure with access to setter and getter methods, but no direct access to the properties.  Something like:

```
var fence = function() {
    var x1, x2, y1, y2; 
    var setX1 = function(x) {
            if (typeof x == 'undefined') return x1;
            if (x != x1) alert('It Changed');
            x1 = x; 
    };
    var setX2 = function(x) {
            if (typeof x == 'undefined') return x2;
            if (x != x2) alert('It Changed');
            x2 = x; 
    };
    var setY1 = function(y) {
            if (typeof x == 'undefined') return y1;
            if (y != y1) alert('It Changed');
            y1 = y; 
    };
    var setY2 = function(y) { 
            if (typeof y == 'undefined') return y1;
            if (y != y2) alert('It Changed');
            y2 = y; 
    };
    return { x1: setX1, 
             x2: setX2, 
             y1: setY1, 
             y2: setY2 
           }
}()

fence.x1(1); //alerts "It changed"
fence.x1(1); //no alert
```

Answer (score 0):

A good approach may be to define a prototype for a fence rather than using a regular object. For a prototype, you can create setter methods rather than directly setting an attribute, and have the setter methods handle tracking changes to variables as well.

The prototype would look something like this:

```
function fence(x1, x2, x3, x4){
  this.x1 = x1;
  ....

  this.changedVars = {};
}

fence.Prototype.setX1 = function(newVal){
 this.x1 = newVal;
 this.changedVars.x1 = true;
};
```

This would collect all changed variables internally. When you ran a method (say, 'rebuildFence'), you would delete the keys you updated from `this.changedVariables`. Keeping all of the setter methods (and getter methods, if you are so inclined), on the prototype will also reduce memory overhead, since you won't be redefining the functions every time you build a fence.